# Disable Wordpress Theme Browser and Plugin Browser

Tags: plugins, themes

Does the Wordpress theme browser have a name? I looked in its code and don't see something spesific and when I search Google I get other topics.

To disable the theme browser and keep upload theme button active, I would like to add some code like:

```
add_filter('theme_browser', '__return_false');
```

Actually I want to disable both the theme browser and the plugin browser. Is there a way to do this but keep the upload theme button active and upload plugin button active?

Answer (score 0):

You can block the API.

```php
add_action('themes_api', 'se_block_api');
add_action('plugins_api', 'se_block_api');
function se_block_api(){
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. That works partly, but then displays an error and also the javascript would still be running I think; slowing the page. I think a filter would be better, if there was one, then that would stop the javascript from trying to load the theme/plugin browsers, at php level. -- But might use your method for a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use action to block themes API, and filter to block plugins API.

```
add_action('themes_api', function() { exit; });
add_filter('plugins_api', function() { return new stdClass(); });
```

If you don't like seeing the spinner, you can just hide it using CSS:

```
add_action('admin_head', function() {
    echo '<style>body.theme-install-php .spinner, body.plugin-install-php .spinner { display: none !important; }</style>';
});
```